# iOS ion-segment "hover" is white

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

in android looking great in dark mode but in iOS no... as can see:
[image]
my css code in variables.css :

```
/* SETTINGS SEGMENTS
=======================================================
=======================================================*/

ion-segment-button {
    --ripple-color: transparent;
    --color: var(--cs-text-primary, #ffffff);
    --color-checked: var(--cs-text-accent, #ff9900);
}


/* SETTINGS SEGMENTS FOR IOS
=======================================================
=======================================================*/

.ios {
    ion-segment {
        min-height: 65px !important;
        ion-segment-button {
            border-color: transparent !important;
            max-width: none !important;
            min-width: 100px !important;
        }
    }
    .segment-button-checked {
        background: transparent !important;
        border-bottom: 2px solid var(--cs-background-accent, #ff9900) !important;
    }
}
```

can advice me what to do?

to make iOS like android without this white background in dark mode